# Flutter: when to use providers and when not to?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and am working on my first app. Architecturally, I've found that there are 3 components that I want to essentially make available anywhere in the app. They are:

- My logger class
- The class that handles API calls to the backend
- The class that manages app settings

As a newbie to Flutter, I thought, "Aha! I want to use these things everywhere, so I should make them providers at the top of the widget tree," which, I suspect, is where things started going wrong.

Just in these three classes, there are a bunch of dependencies. The settings class depends on a SharedPreferences instance, which has an async getInstance() method. One of the app settings is 'loglevel,' so when I instantiate appsettings I want to pass in my logger so appsettings can read the loglevel setting and set that on the logger. The clientAPI manager handles authentication, and stores the user's refresh token in appsettings, so the clientAPI, depends on app settings too.

I set these three providers up in main.dart as such:

```
void main() async {

  //Get the sharedPrefs needed for the app settings
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        //Create a logger provider
        Provider<OYTLogger>(create: (ctx) => OYTLogger(ctx, Severity.INFO, null, null)),

        //AppSettings logs stuff with the logger provider
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<OYTLogger, AppSettings>(
          create: (ctx) => AppSettings(prefs, Provider.of<OYTLogger>(ctx)),
          update: (BuildContext ctx, OYTLogger logger, AppSettings? settings) => AppSettings(prefs, logger),
        ),

        //OYTClientAPI needs to be a provider because it holds a reference to auth data, which has state
        //that is shared across screens. It also stores data in appsettings.
        Provider<OYTClientAPI>(create: (ctx) => OYTClientAPI(ctx)),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

I suspect this is probably the second point at which things went wrong.

Things were working and then... they weren't. I was able to navigate to the login screen and enter my creds and call the backend API and get an access token and a refresh token, until I must have edited my code to do things that I don't understand because now I'm getting an error "Tried to listen to an InheritedWidget in a life-cycle that will never be called again" and I don't understand why:

```
FlutterError (Tried to listen to an InheritedWidget in a life-cycle that will never be called again.
This error typically happens when calling Provider.of with `listen` to `true`,
in a situation where listening to the provider doesn't make sense, such as:
- initState of a StatefulWidget
- the "create" callback of a provider

This is undesired because these life-cycles are called only once in the
lifetime of a widget. As such, while `listen` is `true`, the widget has
no mean to handle the update scenario.

To fix, consider:
- passing `listen: false` to `Provider.of`
- use a life-cycle that handles updates (like didChangeDependencies)
- use a provider that handles updates (like ProxyProvider).)
```

I'm getting the error on my splash screen. The splash screen shows an image in a Center() widget and sets a 3 second timer. When the timer expires, the AppSettings provider is consulted for the FirstSetupWizardIsCommplete and IsRefreshTokenValid attributes. If I have a valid refresh token I attempt to refresh it and get a current access token for the user. Depending on whether or not the setup wizard is finished I navigate to the setup wizard, the user's home screen, or the logon screen.

The build method of the SplashScreen looks like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final logger = Provider.of<OYTLogger>(context, listen: false);
    final appSettings = Provider.of<AppSettings>(context, listen: false); //<== debugger stops here 
    final clientAPI = Provider.of<OYTClientAPI>(context, listen: false);

    logger.d("", "Starting timer");

    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      logger.d("", "timer expired");
      //do stuff with AppSettings and ClientAPI to figure out
      //which screen to send the user to.
```

I have several questions:

1. Why am I getting this error?

   1. I have listen:false in my code
   2. The build method CAN be called again... right?
2. Is it appropriate to make the logger, the clientAPI, and the appSettings classes providers? Why or why not?
3. Is there a better way to structure my code here? I could probably create a logger and a clientAPI class in each of my screens and only have appSettings as a provider, but it sure seems easier to instantiate them once as providers and reuse them everywhere... (Actually, I could probably instantiate an appSettings on each screen if I had to...)

EDIT: I solved the problem by setting listen: false in the create attribute of the ChangeNotifierProxyProvider in main.dart where AppSettings is given a proxied instance of Logger. But I still feel that I don't fully grok what's going on here and if there's wisdom that anyone would like to pass on, I'll certainly listen.

Comment: There are lots of opinions about how to best do "dependency injection".  Provider is one common option.  Search for "flutter dependency injection" and read other people's opinion to get a better idea of what you want to use.

Comment: Starting new projects with provider package is discouraged.  If you would have chosen provider, choose Riverpod instead.